# Align rectangles inside circle

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a circle and I need to fill this circle by rectangles. Something like this:
[image]

Is there some algorithm for this or advice where to start?
I use fabric.js for drawing. This is [playground](http://jsbin.com/siwajunawe/edit?js,output). But, the question is more about math probably. I think there should be some formula, I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go with "close enough" for now: subtract the rectangle length from the radius, then multiply the result by 2π. That's the inner circumference. Now divide that by the rectangle width (and round down) to get the number of rectangles. Divide 360° by that to get the angles at which to draw them.

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/napecagado/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand some points. You said subtract the rectangle lenght. By length, do you mean height? Another question, what I have to divide by 360 degrees? And, I don't understand how I can calculate x,y coordinates.

Comment: By length I mean the long side, the difference between inner and outer radius. Looking at your JSBin, it's the height, yes. I'm going to update my answer with a JSBin soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for the demo and your time. I will try to understand how it works.

Comment: I'm calculating the radius of the circle that runs through the centers of the rectangles. Then I use a loop to walk through the angles I need and position my rectangles using cos/sin to calculate the point on the circle where the rect's center goes. Finally I rotate the rectangle using the angle + 90°

Answer (score 1):

I have updated a JSBin file you provided. I have commented out the code in lots of details, so I don't have explain alot here.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.querySelector('#my-canvas'));

var circleRadius = 250;
var boxHeight = 30;
var boxWidth = 150;

function createCircleAndBoxes(radius, boxHeight, boxWidth) {
  var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: circleRadius,
    fill: '#f3aa25',
    stroke: '#333'
  });
  canvas.add(circle);

  // Calculates the center of the circle
  circle.left = (canvas.width - circle.width) / 2;
  circle.top = (canvas.height - circle.width) / 2;

  // The inner lines of the boxes make a circle
  // Calculate the circumference of this circle.
  // By dividing the height of the box by the calculated circumference
  // We can get the number of boxes needed
  var innerCircumference = 2 * Math.PI * (circleRadius - boxWidth);
  var roughBoxCount = Math.floor(innerCircumference / boxHeight);

  // Each box is placed exactly at the center of the circle
  var calculatedTop = circle.top + (circle.height / 2) - 1;
  var calculatedLeft = circle.left + (circle.width / 2) + 1;
  // By changing the origin to a negative point away from the box,
  // the box is translated. Also, all rotatopms are done from this point
  // The trick however is that, the origin point is calculated
  // as a percentage of the height and width. For instance, 0.5 means center
  // Therefore, we align the origin point with the circle center and 
  // calculate the offset as a percentage
  var calculatedOriginX = (boxWidth - circleRadius) / boxWidth;
  var calculatedOriginY = (boxHeight / 2) / boxHeight;

  // Since we have the number of boxes needed, we can calculate
  // what's the angle each box needs to be rotated
  var calculatedAngle = 360 / roughBoxCount;

  // Combine all these, and you got your requirement
  for(var i = 0; i<roughBoxCount; i++) {    
    var rect  = new fabric.Rect({
        angle: calculatedAngle * i,
        top: calculatedTop,
        left: calculatedLeft,
        centeredRotation: false,
        originX: calculatedOriginX,
        originY: calculatedOriginY,
        width: boxWidth,
        height: boxHeight,
        fill: '#e3e3e3',
        stroke: '#333'
    });
    canvas.add(rect);
  }
}

createCircleAndBoxes(circleRadius, boxHeight, boxWidth);
```

Learn about translations, rotations and center point calculations, which is the key for this kind of development. My approach is slightly different to the answer above by 'user348173'. But I guess, both are worth going through

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xixetifora/1/edit?js,output)